# C,Reading From File,Prinintg, Syntax Error identifier

Tags: c, syntax-error

Im trying to run my c code.
but im getting a problem and really tried that much to get the right thing and i couldnt know what the problem.
what is visual studio telling me that, i have syntax error
also missed "}"
but i checked every thing and its still give me the error if there is an error cause of structure
please tell me how to fix this but if its another help me to get the right think
thank you so much.
this is my code below.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef struct University
{
    Student* arr;
}University;
typedef struct Student
{
    char* name;
    long id;
    float grade;
    char labor[5];
    char finalg;

}Student;
int readfile(University uni);
void outputfile(University uni, int n);
int main()
{
    int n;
    University uni;
    n=readfile(uni);
    outputfile(uni, n);

    return 0;
}
int readfile(University uni)
{
    FILE* fp;
    char name[100], ch[5];
    long id;
    float grade;
    int cnt = 0, i, j;
    fp = fopen("input.txt", "rt");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Cannot open input file.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s %l %f %c", name, &id, &grade, &ch) > 0)
    {
        if (cnt == 0)
        {
            uni.arr = (Student*)malloc(1 * sizeof(Student));
            if (uni.arr == NULL)
            {
                printf("No Memory to allocation.\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            cnt++;
        }
        else if (cnt >= 1)
        {
            uni.arr = (Student*)realloc(uni.arr, (cnt + 1) * sizeof(Student));
            if (uni.arr == NULL)
            {
                printf("No Memory to allocation.\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            cnt++;
        }
        for (i = cnt - 1; i < cnt;i++)
        {
            uni.arr[i].name = (char*)malloc((strlen(name) + 1) * sizeof(char));
            if (uni.arr[i].name == NULL)
            {
                printf("No Memory to allocation.\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            uni.arr[i].id = id;
            uni.arr[i].grade = grade;
            for (j = 0;j < 5;j++)
                uni.arr[i].labor[j] = ch[j];
        }
    }
    return cnt;
}
void outputfile(University uni, int n)
{
    FILE* fo;
    int i,check,j;
    fo = fopen("outputfile.txt", "w");
    for (i = 0;i < n;i++)
    {
        check = 0;
        for (j = 0;j < 5;j++)
            if (uni.arr[i].labor[j] == 1)
                check++;
        if (check < 3)
            check = 0;
        else
            check = 1;
        fprintf(fo,"Student[%d]: %s %.2f %d", i+1,uni.arr[i].name,uni.arr[i].grade,check);
    }
}
```

the inputfile is :

```
michel 123 90.1 11001
alex 234 92.3 10011
Linda 345 89.4 10001
Shoco 456 90.6 01001
```

the outfile that i want is :

```
Student 1: michel 123 90.1 1
Student 2: alex 234 92.3 1
Student 3: Shoco 456 90.6 0
……………..
…………….
Student n: Shoco 456 90.6 0
```

Comment: Please add the full error message to the question.

Comment: You have `Student* arr;` before you define the `Student` typedef. Switch the order of the `University` and `Student` typedefs.

Comment: `%l` is not a valid format specifier. It should be `%ld`.

Comment: I don't get any error about missing `}` when I compile your code.

Comment: this is the problem C4700 uninitialized local variable 'uni' used Project8

Comment: Structures are passed by value. So when you pass `uni` to `readfile()`, it updates a local copy of the structure, not the variable in `main()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Syntax errors

In the C Playground ([editable](https://cplayground.com/?p=axolotl-albatross-okapi)) I get the following errors:

```
/cplayground/code.cpp:7:5: error: unknown type name 'Student'
    Student* arr;
    ^
```

Here, in the definition of University, you are referencing Student before it has been defined.  Move the definition of Student to before University and it'll work.

The following errors all belong together, explained below:

```
/cplayground/code.cpp:42:29: warning: invalid conversion specifier ' ' [-Wformat-invalid-specifier]
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s %l %f %c", name, &id, &grade, &ch) > 0)
                         ~~~^
/cplayground/code.cpp:42:44: warning: format specifies type 'float *' but the argument has type 'long *' [-Wformat]
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s %l %f %c", name, &id, &grade, &ch) > 0)
                             ~~            ^~~
                             %ld
/cplayground/code.cpp:42:49: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'float *' [-Wformat]
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s %l %f %c", name, &id, &grade, &ch) > 0)
                                ~~              ^~~~~~
                                %f
```

These all relate to the use of `%l` which is not a complete specifier.  The first error tells you this, the other two are because the following specifiers and arguments are out of sync.  Fix the first error, the rest will go away.

Finally:

```
/cplayground/code.cpp:42:57: warning: data argument not used by format string [-Wformat-extra-args]
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s %l %f %c", name, &id, &grade, &ch) > 0)
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~                     ^
4 warnings and 1 error generated.
```

Here you have used `%c` to indicate a single char, but are passing a `char **` (address of the `ch` array).  I suspect you want `%s` for a C string, and then you'll want to pick just the first element if that's what your intended output wants (NB: C Playground lets you upload a ZIP containing test input files, look under the cog option if you want to try it there).

## Argument passing by value

In the definition and implementation of `readfile` and `outputfile` you are passing by value.  This means that the function is updating a copy of the `uni` variable and not the one passed.  So anything added by `readfile` won't reach `outputfile`.

```
int readfile(University uni);
void outputfile(University uni, int n);
```

You need to change the declaration and implementation to pass a pointer, thus:

```
int readfile(University *uni);
void outputfile(University *uni, int n);
```

Then, within both functions, change the `.` accessor to `->` to dereference the pointer.  e.g.

```
uni->arr = (Student*)malloc(1 * sizeof(Student));
if (uni->arr == NULL)
```

## Logic errors

There are other logic errors that prevent it from running correctly, but I'll leave that for the OP.

Notably, the `for` loop after allocating the new student is unnecessary (it'll only ever loop once, its meant to be targetting the 'empty' element at the end of the array).

A good thing to do here would be to get a pointer to the last element, then use that to simplify the logic.

```
Student *student = uni->arr[cnt-1];
strcpy(student->name, name);
//...
```

You also forgot to copy over the name.

If there is no input file, you should `exit()` rather than return, or you'll get a segmentation fault.

There's more besides by the looks of things, but hopefully this takes you further, and you can come back then.

Here is an [updated playground](https://cplayground.com/?p=gnu-opossum-bird) that get's as far as the logic errors.

Comment: First of all , thank you so much for the wornderfull explain 
i really understand my faults and im goind to learn from this 
im trying to run the code in visual studio i get this error 
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'ch' was corrupted.
any explain ?
i checked the ch is all right

Comment: It suggests that you are overwriting the `ch` variable, out-of-bounds or similar.  You defined it as `char ch[5]`, and the `input.text` has 5 characters in that position.  For a C string, you need to allow for the terminating NULL character, so `ch` should have at least 6 elements to avoid out-of-bounds.  Check the docs on `fscanf` to see how you can specify the maximum width of each specifier to avoid such corruptions.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a pointers issue with structure building in university struct
You need to rewrite the pointers.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Show which lines have the error, and how to rewrite it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go look into your compilers error, there's plenty of them!
For example:

```
main.c:66:23: error: request for member ‘name’ in something not a structure or union
   66 |             uni.arr[i].name = (char*)malloc((strlen(name) + 1) * sizeof(char));
      |                       ^
main.c:67:27: error: request for member ‘name’ in something not a structure or union
   67 |             if (uni.arr[i].name == NULL)
      |                           ^
main.c:72:23: error: request for member ‘id’ in something not a structure or union
   72 |             uni.arr[i].id = id;
      |                       ^
main.c:73:23: error: request for member ‘grade’ in something not a structure or union
   73 |             uni.arr[i].grade = grade;
      |                       ^
main.c:75:27: error: request for member ‘labor’ in something not a structure or union
   75 |                 uni.arr[i].labor[j] = ch[j];
```